# Why does adding a border change the behavior of the background color?

Tags: html, css

In the example below why does removing the border on the #enclosing div make the background lightblue color not fill the entire div background anymore?

```
#enclosing
{
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#outer
{
  margin: 40px;
}

#inner
{
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}​

<div id="enclosing">
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">This is nested div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Neodymium/v8juj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `outer` div has margin, which needs something to "push" against.

When the enclosing div has no border (or padding), there is nothing for the margin of the `outer` div to push against.

Adding border or padding to the top/bottom of the div gives it the necessary containment for the `outer` div to calculate off of.

I believe this is what's known as `collapsing margins` in the [Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: solid answer.  If you want the thick blue border there even without the border, use padding instead of margin on `#outer` and you should see the same results with or without the border.